# how to restart my tp-link router from java

Tags: java, router

I need to restart my router from java(or any script that can do this every 5 minute!)

I tried this but my problem is when I execute this command "telnet 192.168.1.1" I can not enter my password.

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start telnet 192.168.1.1");
```

and after this code I see this on screen and I don't know how to enter my pass to it from my java code!!

[image]

Comment: Use Java Client Socket api to talk to the port, just like you would use Telnet from the command line.

Comment: @MinhKieu I connected through socket but I don't know what should I send to restart it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it.

just by using chrome driver:)